# How to inject a ViewModel that has constructor injection with Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, dependency-injection

I registered my view model and DialogMessage service like this:

```
public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DependencyService.Register<IDialogMessage, DialogMessage>();
        DependencyService.Register<SignInViewModel>();

        MainPage = new AppShell();
    }
```

SignInViewModel has DialogMessage service injected into its constructor

```
public SignInViewModel(IDialogMessage dialogMessage)
    {
       _dialogMessage = dialogMessage;
    }
```

Now, I want to set SignInViewModel as binding context of SignInView in its code behind class by injecting it:

```
public SignInPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = DependencyService.Resolve<SignInViewModel>();
    }
```

This however results in following exception:

> Default constructor not found for type AppName.ViewModels.SignInViewModel   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceMono (System.Boolean nonPublic, System.Boolean wrapExceptions

How to inject SignInViewModel to binding context along with injecting DialogMessage service to SignInViewModel?

Comment: I think that Xamarin.Forms by itself does not provide dependecy constructor, so you will need to modify your constructor to accept 0 parameters and resolve the dependency using the `DependencyService`

Comment: Follow on to that comment: after adding the parameterless constructor, code will be something like `var vm = DependencyService.Resolve<SignInViewModel>(); vm.DialogMessage = dialogMessage; BindingContext = vm;` You will have to come up with an appropriate "dialogMessage", that is meaningful to pass to that vm.